# Apache is running... but not serving, after reinstalling PHP

Tags: apache-2.2

I used to have a happy, shiny instance of apache running on my Mavericks OS X MBP. Then I reinstall PHP with PostgreSQL extensions vie Homebrew ([this walkthrough](http://justinhileman.info/article/reinstalling-php-on-mac-os-x/)). I am not sure how PHP was installed before. I installed the new version on top of whatever other PHP instances I had previously.

```
brew install php54 --with-mysql --with-apache --with-pgsql=/usr/local/opt/postgresql
```

The reinstall went well and everything seemed to be in place. At the end, I restarted Apache without any errors and browsed back to my website. It's gone! Apache isnt responding to any of the websites I had previously set up and working.

1. I checked the Apache logs and there were no new entries since the reinstall

   1. Checked general log at `/private/var/log/apache2/error_log`
   2. Checked the logs for each site in vhost config.
2. If I run `sudo apachectl start` again, I get `org.apache.httpd: Already loaded`
3. I checked on `top`, `ps` and Activity Monitor and I dont see `httpd` on any of them.
4. If I run `php` on the command line, I dont get any errors, just the blank prompt waiting for input... which I would expect.
5. Apache isn't serving PHP or flat HTML.

Clearly I screwed something up in the reinstall but I cant believe that the logs arent even working. Apache says its running. The OS says it isnt. Nothing is getting served. Where are the logs?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? If there was a problem with the question, I'd gladly fix it if the downvoter left feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This happened when I upgraded to Mavericks too.  I removed individual site configs, than added them back in one at a time until I narrowed it down.

I think it turned out to be a broken Apache or PHP module, but it has been a while.  Also, I had to re-install a bunch of xcode libs to get Pear working again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I manually deleted all php-related files and folders in `/etc` and `/usr` and apache is running again. I have no idea if this was a good idea or not but at least Im making progress for now